# C# Regex Match 15 Characters, Single Spaces, Alpha-Numeric

Tags: c#, regex

I need to match a string under the following conditions using Regex in C#:

1. Entire string can only be alphanumeric (including spaces).
2. Must be a maximum of 15 characters or less (including spaces).
3. First & last characters can only be a letter.
4. A single space can appear multiple times in anywhere but the first and last characters of the string. (Multiple spaces together should not be allowed).
5. Capitalization should be ignored.
6. Should match the WHOLE word(s).

If any one of these preconditions are broken, a match should not follow.

Here is what i currently have:

```
^\b([A-z]{1})(([A-z0-9 ])*([A-z]{1}))?\b$
```

And here are some test strings that should match:

- Stack OverFlow
- Iamthe greatest
- A
- superman23s
- One Two Three

And some that shouldn't match (note the spaces):

- Stack [double_space] Overflow Rocks
- 23Hello
- ThisIsOver15CharactersLong
- Hello23
- [space_here]hey

etc.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is the problem with your regex?

Comment: Problem is that it's matching double spaces when i only want it to match one. The only reason i shared all the irrelevant details is because i didn't want my possibly incorrect Regex to burden others trying to match the conditions i set out.

Comment: How does your first string matches? It's over 15 characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `lookaheads`

```
                                                               |->matches if all the lookaheads are true
                                                               --
^(?=[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z\d\s]+[a-zA-Z])?$)(?=.{1,15}$)(?!.*\s{2,}).*$
-------------------------------------- ----------  ----------
                 |                       |           |->checks if there are no two or more space occuring
                 |                       |->checks if the string is between 1 to 15 chars
                 |->checks if the string starts with alphabet followed by 1 to many requireds chars and that ends with a char that is not space
```

you can try it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Comment: Ah, the old multiple-lookaheads-to-match-multiple-conditions trick. (By "old", I meant "I learned about this in the past 48 hours".) Very nice, although the first lookahead requires at least two characters

Comment: This allows last char to be a number - OP states last char to be a letter only

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ No probs :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex: -

```
"^([a-zA-Z]([ ](?=[a-zA-Z0-9])|[a-zA-Z0-9]){0,13}[a-zA-Z])$"
```

**Explanation : -**

```
[a-zA-Z]    // Match first character letter

(                         // Capture group
    [ ](?=[a-zA-Z0-9])    // Match either a `space followed by non-whitespace` (Avoid double space, but accept single whitespace)
            |             // or
    [a-zA-Z0-9]           // just `non-whitespace` characters

){0,13}                  // from `0 to 13` character in length

[a-zA-Z]     // Match last character letter
```

**Update : -**

To handle single characters, you can make the pattern after 1st character optional as nicely pointed by `@Rawling` in comments: -

```
"^([a-zA-Z](([ ](?=[a-zA-Z0-9])|[a-zA-Z0-9]){0,13}[a-zA-Z])?)$"
         ^^^                                            ^^^
     use a capture group                           make it optional
```

Comment: Very nice, although again this demands at least two characters in the input, and further restricts the last character to a letter rather than a letter or digit.

Comment: @Rawling.. I thought OP don't want last character to be `digit` from this string - `Hello23`. He don't want to match this. But, it can be modified.

Comment: @Rawling. For your first concern, I need to take a look to modify. Please wait.

Comment: Huh, good point about the trailing digit - the rules don't say it's not allowed, but the examples do exclude it.

Comment: @Rawling.. Well, I think this needs a major modification to make use of `more look-aheads`. :( Or, a simple but of course weird way is to include that as an alternative using `pipe`.

Comment: @Rawling.. Yeah, rules don't say it.

Comment: Can't you just make the whole part after the first `[a-zA-Z]` optional with a `(...)?` ?

Comment: @Rawling.. Oh! Man. You are awesome. Will just do a quick edit.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify the last character should only be a letter. Updated OP.

Comment: @user1684699.. Yeah, you can take my last regex. Would work perfectly, for all cases.

Comment: @user1684699.. I have also added an explanation which I think would be enough to make you understand. Even if you have any doubt, you can ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

And my version, again using look-aheads:

```
^(?=.{1,15}$)(?=^[A-Z].*)(?=.*[A-Z]$)(?![ ]{2})[A-Z0-9 ]+$
```

explained:

```
^               start of string
(?=.{1,15}$)    positive look-ahead: must be between 1 and 15 chars
(?=^[A-Z].*)    positive look-ahead: initial char must be alpha
(?=.*[A-Z]$)    positive look-ahead: last char must be alpha
(?![ ]{2})      negative look-ahead: string mustn't contain 2 or more consecutive spaces
[A-Z0-9 ]+      if all the look-aheads agree, select only alpha-numeric chars + space
$               end of string
```

This will also need the IgnoreCase option setting

Comment: `(?![ ]{2}` should be `(?!.*[ ]{2}`